# tool for finding which functions can ultimately cause a call to a (list of) low level functions

Tags: c++, static-analysis, call-graph

I have a very large C++ program where certain low level functions should only be called from certain contexts or while taking specific precautions. I am looking for a tool that shows me which of these low-level functions are called by much higher level functions. I would prefer this to be visible in the IDE with some drop down or labeling, possibly in annotated source output, but any easier method than manually searching the call-graph will help.

This is a problem of static analysis and I'm not helped by a profiler.

I am mostly working on mac, linux is OK, and if something is only available on windows then I can live with that.

*Update*

*Just having the call-graph does not make it that much quicker to answer the question, "does foo() potentially cause a call to x() y() or z()". (or I'm missing something about the call-graph tools, perhaps I need to write a program that traverses it to get a solution?)*

Comment: Are you able to wrap those calls into a class or namespace that's only accessible in the contexts in which it's valid to call? Instead of searching for bogus call points, just prevent them up front and the compiler will tell you before the mistake is made.

Comment: cscope is a nifty tool that can give you such information like - which  functions call a particular function, which functions are called by a particular function. And I think it works well for c++ code too. I had used it sometime ago for digging into GCC code.

Comment: wrapping them in a namespace seems doable, but it will be a huge amount of work and change the coding style a bit. Maybe we'll just have to live with that.

Comment: A call graph encodes A-directly-calls-B. To determine if A calls Z, you need to take the transitive closure of the directly-calls relation. (One could build a call graph will all of that, but it would be thick with indirectly-calls edges and that's mostly not useful).

Comment: For my particular purpose A-Z *search or lookup* would be very useful, I have some functions that should not be called from certain threads (and some that may only be called with e.g. certain locks held), and I want to automate and auto check the work done in moving supposedly safe functions to those threads. It would definitely not be useful to visualize the whole thing, I just want a marker on each function weather it's "dirty" in the sense of "may cause a call", then I can continue manually from there (relatively) easily.

Answer (score 1):

There exists [Clang Static Analyzer](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) which uses LLVM which should also be present on OS X. Actually i'm of the opinion that this is integrated in Xcode. Anyway, there exists a GUI.

Furthermore there are several LLVM [passes](http://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html), where you can generate call graphs, but i'm not sure if this is what you want.

Comment: It's there for sure, but how do I use it to answer the question "could foo() cause a call to x(), y(), or z()"?

Comment: A control flow graph (CFG) should represent also conditional calls. So, whenever there occurs somewhere a call to a function it is represented within the graph and this can be detected by transferring the CFG and finding direct or indirect dependencies between the functions.

Comment: I understand what it is, but I can't find anything like that in Xcode or in the static analyzer documentation you link to. From clang/llvm I seem to be able to save the call-graph and then could likely write my own program to answer my questions

Comment: Right, this is possibly the correct way. I just saw the screenshot on the clang site. But possibly there exists no such implementation yet.

Comment: Regarding my last comment: There exists an ACM scientific [paper](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=151643) "Efficient call graph analysis" by Mary W. Hall and Ken Kennedy maybe you'll get it somwhere.

Answer (score 1):

The tool [Scientific Toolworks "Understand"](http://www.scitools.com) tool is supposed to be able to produce call graphs for C and C++.

[Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.org) also supposedly produces call graphs.

I don't have any experience with either of these, but some harsh opinions.  You need to keep in mind that I'm a vendor of another tool, so take this opinion with a big grain of salt.

I have experience building [reasonably accurate call graphs](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/FlowAnalysis.html#CallGraphAnalysis) for massive C systems (25 million lines) with 250,000 functions.

One issue I encounter in building a realistic call graph are indirect function calls, and for C++, overloaded method function calls.  In big systems, there are a lot of both of these.    To determine what gets called when FOO gets invoked, your tool has to have to deep semantic understanding of how the compiler/language resolves an overloaded call, and for indirect function calls, a reasonably precise determination of what a function pointer might actually point-to in a big system.  If you don't get these reasonably right, your call graph will contain a lot of false positives (e.g., bogus claims of A calls B), and on scale false positives are a disaster.

For C++, you must have what amounts to the full compiler front end.  Neither Understand or Doxygen have this, so I don't see how they can actually understand C++'s overloading/Koenig lookup rules.   Neither Understand or Doxygen make any attempt that I know of to reason about indirect function calls.

Our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) does build calls graphs for C reasonably well, even with indirect function pointers, using a [C-language precise front end](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/CFrontEnd.html).

We have [C++ language precise front end](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/CFrontEnd.html), and it does the overload resolution correctly (to the extent the C++ committee agrees on it, and we understand what they said, and what the individual compilers do [they don't always agree]), and we have something like Doxygen that shows this information.  We don't presently have function pointer analysis for C++ but we are working on it (we have full control flow graphs *within* methods and that's a big step).

I understand [CLANG](http://www.clang.org) has some option for computing call graphs, and I'd expect that to be accurate on overloads since Clang is essentially a C++ compiler implemented with a bunch of components.    I don't know what, if anything Clang does to analyze function pointers.